# Apache Spark: Limit number of executors used by Spark App

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to limit the number of executors used by an App on Spark? I am able to set the initial amount of executors with `spark.executor.instances` but later on in my app it seems that Spark will on its own add all available executors it can.

This makes it to where no other jobs can run on the cluster at the same time.  Googling has led me to know solution but `spark.cores.max` which doesn't seem to work to limit the total number of executors...

Answer (score 3):

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=infinity
```

This property is infinity by default, you can set this property to limit the number of executors.

Comment: We faced similar issue,  even though i/o through is limited it started allocating more executors. Then we looked into this property